# what is the difference in usage of 'pertain' and 'appertain'?

Tags: word-usage

In the dictionary the meanings of these two words seem interchangeable so why do the two words exist? Are there different contexts for their usage?

Definitions by Merriam-Webster:

> Definition of PERTAIN
>
> 1
>
> - a (1) : to belong as a part, member, accessory, or product (2) : to belong as an attribute, feature, or function <the destruction pertaining to war> (3) : to belong as a duty or right <rights that pertain to fatherhood>
> - b : to be appropriate to something <which rule pertains?>
>
> 2
>
> - : to have reference <books pertaining to birds>

---

> Definition of APPERTAIN
>
> - : to belong or be connected as a rightful part or attribute : PERTAIN

Comment: There seems little point in remarking upon similar definitions when looking for differences between two words. Did you find any differences or contexts with different uses?

Answer (score 3):

There is considerable overlap in meaning, but the most striking feature is that *pertain* seems to be far more popular. Records for *pertain* in the Corpus of Contemporary American English outnumber those for *appertain* by 120 to 1. The contrast in usage in British English is nowhere nearly as pronounced, but the British National Corpus still shows a preference for *pertain* by almost 3 to 1. The preference is confirmed, if not as decisively, by citations in the Oxford English Dictionary, where those containing *pertain* are more than one and a half times greater in number than those containing *appertain*.

Comment: ...Could you add where do the words *don't* overlap in meaning? I checked the dictionary entries and didn't notice any meaningful differences.

Comment: @SF. One meaning of _pertain_ which _appertain_ doesn’t have is ‘To apply; to be or remain in place; to continue to be applicable.’ The OED has seven main definitions for _appertain_ and four for _pertain_, each with several subsidiary definitions, so I don’t think it’s feasible to give any more detail here.

Answer (score 3):

Pertain conveys an association with--at least in part.  Appertain conveys a total association with.

Comment: Supporting evidence? Or, sources/citations?

Answer (score 0):

I've seen that *appertain* also has a cool usage pattern that *pertain* doesn't seem to, which is that the verb form can be used by itself, without anything connecting it to the thing it refers to. Consider the following:

"That feature pertains to the situation at hand."

If that's the case, you might also just say:

"That feature appertains."

It's then left to the listener to understand what it refers to, but when that's obvious, it works as a nice terse usage. I don't think "pertain" admits this kind of usage.

Answer (score 0):

I have heard it said that "appertaining" also was used mostly in the context of royalty: Kings and Queens and their heirs.

Here's an example:
"After the reading of that paragraph in the Gracious Speech from the Throne, I have now to ask leave of the House to introduce a Bill which will enable Her Majesty to add to the Royal Style and Titles appertaining to the Imperial Crown of the United Kingdom and its Dependencies..."

https://hansard.parliament.uk/Commons/1876-02-17/debates/7bc99eb8-eac8-415f-ae07-c3c5005ee585/RoyalTitlesBill?__cf_chl_f_tk=5JVY4.QFQqgCTU6M2VqX9ltaNTZdOfMoM.N9Bz7eeKY-1706303287-0-gaNycGzNDbs

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).